# How can I reserve my GPU for only executing Python scripts?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, python, cuda

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 trying to run a PyTorch script and get

`torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 86.00 MiB (GPU 0; 3.81 GiB total capacity; 3.18 GiB already allocated; 80.81 MiB free; 3.18 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)`

`prime-select query` yields the following:

```
on-demand
```

`lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` yields the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
```

`nvidia-smi` yields the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.05    Driver Version: 525.85.05    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P0    N/A /  35W |      7MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1464      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1743      G   ...ome-remote-desktop-daemon        1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In my Ubuntu `About` settings, "Graphichs" is shown as:

```
NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] / Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
```

How can i stop my gpu being used for `Xorg` and for the `gnome-remote-desktop-daemon`? I only  want to use my gpu with PyTorch. Using the `torch.cuda.memory_allocated` and `torch.cuda.memory_reserved` functions shows that I'm using `0.0GB` of my gpu despite recognizing the Nvidia gpu, so I'm confused haha.

If anyone needs more info please let me know (:

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197286/how-can-i-flush-gpu-memory-using-cuda-physical-reset-is-unavailable but you might not have enough memory on your device to run that script properly depending on the script you are running.  However, killing Xorg from being used by the GPU may render your GUI not working and you may not be able to see what you are doing.  That being said, you might be able to get it to fully work without the GUI or maybe use a different desktop version, i.e. Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc that doesn't use as much resources.

Comment: @Terrance thanks! Do you know if there's a way to force Xorg to use the cpu instead? I tried the `nvidia-smi --gpu-reset` command from the link but the gpu is in use (by Xorg/desktop daemon I assume). You're right about killing Xorg, definitely messes up the gui haha

Comment: I wish I had integrated graphics on my system to actually help on things like this, but unfortunately, I don't.  There are answers out there were you can use the Intel for the display then use the NVIDIA for CUDA.  One to see is https://askubuntu.com/questions/869496/force-xorg-to-use-cpu-not-gpu and I am certain that there are others out there.  Just to let you know, even if an answer was written for 14.04 there is still a good chance that it will work with newer versions like 22.04.

Comment: Okay that's super helpful thank you so much, I'll play around with it and hopefully not blow everything up (: